# read file(not utf-8) line by line?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to read file line by line, if it is not in utf-8 encoding with `std::io::File` and `std::io::BufReader`?

I look at `std::io::Lines` and it return `Result<String>`, so
I worry, have I implement my own `BufReader` that do the same, but return `Vec<u8>` instead, or I can reuse `std::io::BufReader` in some way?

Comment: If it's not UTF-8, which encoding is your program expecting?

Comment: @E_net4 one byte encoding - several windows os based, like windows-1253

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to re-implement `BufReader` itself, it provides exactly the method you need for your usecase [`read_until`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until):

```
fn read_until(&mut self, byte: u8, buf: &mut Vec<u8>) -> Result<usize>
```

You supply your own `Vec<u8>` and the content of the file will be appended until `byte` is encountered (0x0A being LF).

There are several potential gotchas:

- the buffer may end not only with a LF byte, but with a CR LF sequence,
- it is up to you to clear `buf` between subsequent calls.

A simple `while let Ok(_) = reader.read_until(0x0A as u8, buffer)` should let you read your file easily enough.

You may consider implement a `std::io::Lines` equivalent which converts from the encoding to UTF-8 to provide a nice API, though it will have a performance cost.

Comment: This comment doesn't address the exact question, but others may find https://crates.io/crates/encoding_rs_io crate very helpful in reading non-UTF-8 files. It doesn't have an option to use BufReader, though.

Comment: How would CR LF be handled correctly with this?

Comment: @Johann150: The key point is that whether LF or CR LF is the end of the line, LF is always the last byte. So you can just pull in the whole line until LF (inclusive), then trim LF, then trim CR.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more simplified version.

There is no double checking if the input is decodable with UTF-8, thus it must be coded in Windows 1252.

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader};

use encoding_rs::WINDOWS_1252;
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let path = PathBuf::from("path/to/your/file.txt");
    let file = File::open(path)?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
                    .encoding(Some(WINDOWS_1252))
                    .build(file));
    
    for (i, rst) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let line_number :u32 = i+1;
        if let Ok(line) = rst {
            // 'line' is decoded String line here
        }
    }
    
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This is the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

To read files (utf-8 or not utf-8) line by line, I use:

```
/*
// Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
encoding_rs = "0.8"
encoding_rs_io = "0.1.7"
...
*/

use encoding_rs::WINDOWS_1252;
use encoding_rs_io::DecodeReaderBytesBuilder;
use std::{
    fs,
    io::{Read, BufRead, BufReader, Error},
};

fn main() {
    let file_path: &str = "/tmp/file.txt";
    let buffer: Box<dyn BufRead> = read_file(file_path);

    for (index, result_vec_bytes) in buffer.split(b'\n').enumerate() {
        let line_number: usize = index + 1;
        let line_utf8: String = get_string_utf8(result_vec_bytes, line_number, file_path);
        println!("{line_utf8}");
    }
}
```

Such that:

```
fn read_file(file_path: &str) -> Box<dyn BufRead> {
    let file = match fs::File::open(file_path) {
        Ok(f) => f,
        Err(why) => panic!("Problem opening the file: \"{file_path}\"\n{why:?}"),
    };
    Box::new(BufReader::new(file))
}
```

And

```
fn get_string_utf8(result_vec_bytes: Result<Vec<u8>, std::io::Error>, line_number: usize) -> String {
    let vec_bytes: Vec<u8> = match result_vec_bytes {
        Ok(values) => values,
        Err(why) => panic!("Failed to read line nº {line_number}: {why}"),
    };

    // from_utf8() checks to ensure that the bytes are valid UTF-8
    let line_utf8: String = match std::str::from_utf8(&vec_bytes) {
        Ok(str) => str.to_string(),
        Err(_) => {
            let mut data = DecodeReaderBytesBuilder::new()
            .encoding(Some(WINDOWS_1252))
            .build(vec_bytes.as_slice());

            let mut buffer = String::new();
            let _number_of_bytes = match data.read_to_string(&mut buffer) {
                Ok(num) => num,
                Err(why) => {
                    eprintln!("Problem reading data from file in buffer!");
                    eprintln!("Line nº {line_number}");
                    eprintln!("Used encoding type: WINDOWS_1252.");
                    eprintln!("Try another encoding type!");
                    panic!("Failed to convert data to UTF-8!: {why}")
                },
            };

            buffer
        }
    };

    // remove Window new line: "\r\n"
    line_utf8.trim_end_matches('\r').to_string()
}
```