# How can I stop a BufReader from reading in Rust when using read_until()?

Tags: io, rust, bufferedreader

I am attempting to use a `BufReader` to load a bunch of data and then use `read_until()` scan the data. However, I am having a hard time discerning when `read_until()` hits EOF and my code wraps back around to the start of the data again, creating an infinite loop. I need to stop reading when `read_until()` hits EOF. How can I accomplish this in Rust?

This is what I have so far:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufRead;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::str;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let f1 = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(f1);
    let mut byte_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
    loop {
        let my_bytes = reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut byte_vec);
        let is_valid_utf8 = str::from_utf8(&byte_vec);

        match is_valid_utf8 {
            Ok(the_str) => println!("{} is a valid UTF-8 String", the_str),
            Err(err) => println!("Error: {}", err),
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

foo.txt just has a few lines of example text. The code will loop forever back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: 1. why not use read_line ? 2. read the documentation 3. read warning

Comment: 1. because read_line() assumes that the data can be parsed as utf8 and I cannot make that assumption in my code.

2. A specific area of documentation would be useful, not just "read the documentation" - that's as useless as my question that you are apparently calling out. In theory, every SO question could be answered with "read the documentation." Come on man.

Comment: [read_until](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until)

Comment: @Stargateur right and after seeing `This function will read bytes from the underlying stream until the newline delimiter (the 0xA byte) or EOF is found. Once found, all bytes up to, and including, the delimiter (if found) will be appended to buf.` this means I have to scan every input group for EOF? There must be a more efficient solution hence the question. I did read that prior to asking, btw.

Comment: `EOF` is not a value. It's a state. It make no sense to search it into the buffer, it doesn't exist as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the warnings that the compiler is giving you, that's why they are there!

```
warning: unreachable expression
  --> src/lib.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     Ok(())
   |     ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_code)] on by default

warning: unused variable: `my_bytes`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:13
  |
8 |         let my_bytes = reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut byte_vec);
  |             ^^^^^^^^ help: consider using `_my_bytes` instead
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
```

The compiler is telling you that

1. Your loop will never exit — that's your infinite loop.
2. You aren't using the return value of `read_until`.

These two things are related. Check the docs for [`read_until`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_until), emphasis mine:

> Read all bytes into buf until the delimiter byte **or EOF** is reached.
>
> [...]
>
> If successful, this function will return the **total number of bytes read**.

Use the value:

```
let my_bytes = reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut byte_vec)?;
if my_bytes == 0 { break };
```

---

Continue reading the docs, emphasis mine:

> all bytes up to, and including, the delimiter (if found) will be **appended to `buf`**

Your `byte_vec` will continue to accumulate every previous line. This is why you believe that the `BufReader` is returning to the beginning of the input. You *probably* wish to [`clear`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.clear) it at the end of each loop iteration.

See also:

- [read file(not utf-8) line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48034486/155423)
- [How to check for EOF in read_line in Rust 1.12?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41210691/155423)
- [How to check for EOF with `read_line()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27475113/155423)

Comment: Thanks shep but I have a question though - what if EOF is at the end of a line? The bytes read will be more than 0. That's my point of confusion. Make sense?

Comment: @the_endian that's fine, it depends on what you want to do. If the string **must** end in a newline, then you'd have to check this somehow, such as by ensuring the last byte read is a newline (`if byte_vec.last() != Some(&b'\n') { continue }` is an easy way to do it). The majority of the time, you want to treat EOF as a newline, and then you don't have to do anything.